# Spring Batch: How to send nchar datatype while sendStringParametersAsUnicode=false is set at the datasource level?

Tags: spring, azure-sql-database, spring-batch, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I have a spring batch application that uses Azure SQL Server as a database.

I have multiple tables - eg:

```
Employee - EmpID(int), Gender(char), EmpName(varchar), DOJ(DateTime2)
Department - DeptID(int), DeptName(nchar), Description(varchar)
```

As I was facing the **DeadlockLoserDataAccessException** issue, I had to set the following configuration in the datasource config xml

```
<property name="connectionProperties" value="sendStringParametersAsUnicode=false;"/>
```

while this works for the **Employee** table. I want to ensure that **nchar** is used for the **CRUD** operations against the **Department** table.

```
private static final String INSERT_BATCH = "Insert into Department values (? ,? , ?)";
private static final String UPDATE_BATCH = "Update Department Set DeptName = ? Where ID = ?";


jdbcTemplate.update(INSERT_BATCH,
        new Object[]{1, "IT", "IT Department"},
        new int[] {Types.INTEGER, Types.NCHAR, Types.VARCHAR}
);


jdbcTemplate.update(UPDATE_BATCH,
        new Object[]{"Information Technology", 1},
        new int[] {Types.NCHAR, Types.INTEGER}
);
```

> Would it still send the datatype as NCHAR for DeptName or it will be
> treated as CHAR ?

Comment: Since you specified the type as `Types.NCHAR`, the jdbcTemplate will send it as such. What makes you think it will send it with a different type? Have you tried that and found it is being sent as `CHAR`?

Comment: As I have set <property name="connectionProperties" value="sendStringParametersAsUnicode=false;"/>, I thought it would force the datatype as char. I will try to print the SQL queries and post.